# When i am registering user observer in Laravel while fetching single user also i'm getting list of all users

Tags: laravel

Getting issue with Laravel Observer
I created a user observer when i'm doing api call in order to fetch single user also i'm getting list of all user exist in table. what i'm doing wrong.

Here my ObserverProvider and UserObserver which i register in app.php

> ObserversServiceProvider

```
namespace App\Providers;
use App\User;
use App\Observers\UserObserver;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ObserversServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
        User::observe(UserObserver::class);
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {
    }

}
```

> UserObserver

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\User;

class UserObserver
{

    /**
     * Listen to the User created event.
     *
     * @param  User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(User $user) {

      // doing something
    }

}
```

> I'm getting list of all user when i'm doing.
>   $user = User::where('user_id',1)->first();

Comment: Could you dump the data of `$user` with the `dd($user);` function. Right after the line `$user = User::where('user_id',1)->first();`.

Comment: Yes i done it same result because flow go to Model boot before api ping and there i'm checking with email if not then list all user may i need to handle it.

Comment: But can you post the output from the dump here, or via a screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried `$user = User::where('user_id', '=', 1)->first();` (added `=`)

Comment: there was issue because of global registration which i don't need fixed by registering in specific model... Thanks for help